# Iterate over a array type object in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to iterate over an array-type object. I printed that object into the browser console. I am getting this value from a third-party UI control. Here is the image :

[image]

Now how can I iterate this **controls** array? I tried with the below code. But nothing comes:

```
element.formGroup.controls.forEach(item =>{
            console.log(item)
        })
```

Comment: `controls` is not an array, it's a simple object. You can use `Object.values(element.formGroup.controls)` to create an array of the values in the object. `Object.keys` and `Object.entries` also exist if you need to look at the key names.

Comment: Another option is `for (const key in element.formGroup.controls) {...}` which will iterate over the keys. You can then access the values through `element.formGroup.controls[key]`.

Comment: @ShamPooSham can you please give an example?

Comment: VelizarStavrev has some good examples in their answer. Is there a specific part you want me to give an example to? I gave a couple of different options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript has Arrays which are in brackets `[]` and Objects which are in `{}`.
You can go over their element with the for..in loop (more on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
const object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

for (const property in object) {
  console.log(`${property}: ${object[property]}`);
}

// Expected output:
// "a: 1"
// "b: 2"
// "c: 3"
```

Or use the Object methods in the documentation (more on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#static_methods):

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};

console.log(Object.values(object1));
// Expected output: Array ["somestring", 42, false]
```

Which gets the values directly in an array.